# Include error when building TensorFlow from source with a different GCC than the system one

Tags: tensorflow, gcc, bazel

I have been trying to build TensorFlow 2.0 from the master branch on a Red Hat Linux Enterprise edition cluster.

The default GCC available is 4.8.5, and it is not possible to compile TensorFlow with it because it uses explicit

```
std=c++14
```

flag which is not available in GCC 4.8.5

Hence, I started using gcc/8.3.0 using a modulefile, which is configured as follows :

```
(tensorflow2.0-master) -bash-4.2$ module show gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5
-------------------------------------------------------------------
/gpfslocalsup/pub/modules-idris/modulefiles/linux-rhel7-x86_64/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5:


module-whatis The GNU Compiler Collection includes front ends for C, C++, Objective-C, Fortran, Ada, and Go, as well as libraries for these languages.
conflict gcc
prepend-path PATH /gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/bin
prepend-path MANPATH /gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/share/man
prepend-path LD_LIBRARY_PATH /gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/lib
prepend-path LIBRARY_PATH /gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/lib
prepend-path LD_LIBRARY_PATH /gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/lib64
prepend-path LIBRARY_PATH /gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/lib64
prepend-path CPATH /gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/include
prepend-path CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/
setenv CC /gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/bin/gcc
setenv CXX /gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/bin/g++
setenv FC /gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/bin/gfortran
setenv F77 /gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/bin/gfortran
setenv F90 /gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/bin/gfortran
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

To compile TensorFlow, I first compiled bazel-0.29.1 and for that I modified the
`tools/cpp/cc_toolchain_config.bzl`

file as follows :

I replaced all occourances of `/usr/bin/gcc`, `/usr/bin/gcov`, `/usr/bin/nm`, `/usr/bin/ar`, `/usr/bin/cpp` with the binaries in PATH as shown above.
I added the include path as shown above, to the list of `cxx_builtin_include_directory` present in the file.

After that I proceeded to build TensorFlow.

The command used was :

```
CC=/gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/bin/gcc bazel --output_user_root=/tmp/ujjwal-builds build --config=opt --config=cuda --config=mkl --config=numa //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package --verbose_failures
```

This ended up giving me the following error :

```
INFO: Analyzed target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /tmp/ujjwal-builds/7d993f307acf01aa765c32a6dcabd368/external/gif/BUILD.bazel:8:1: undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '@gif//:gif':
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'external/gif/gif_err.c':
  '/gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/include/stddef.h'
  '/gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/include/stdarg.h'
  '/gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/include/stdbool.h'
  '/gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/include/stdint.h'
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 2.152s, Critical Path: 1.63s
INFO: 7 processes: 7 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

I have tried to search for solutions online but there are no satisfactory solutions.  Can anyone please help me with what is going on here as it is important for me.

If it helps, I have attached the output of gcc and g++ include paths below :

```
gcc -E -xc++ - -v
Reading specs from /gpfs7kro/gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/specs
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /gpfs7kw/linkhome/idris/softmgr/softmgr01/spack/var/spack/stage/gcc-8.3.0-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/spack-src/configure --prefix=/gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3 --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --with-mpfr=/gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/mpfr/3.1.6/gcc-4.8.5-vwx7snyrzymeg5n6f7dg5tbpgk35do3k --with-gmp=/gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gmp/6.1.2/gcc-4.8.5-5odxtlxihbfjtj4dxo52oz5f7r6ir6jk --enable-lto --with-quad --with-system-zlib --with-mpc=/gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/mpc/1.1.0/gcc-4.8.5-pogagquauxex67doa7v2mkas2gcs5xut --with-isl=/gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/isl/0.18/gcc-4.8.5-3wslknueis6r2nx3tasaizgda2ianxfa
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.3.0 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /gpfs7kro/gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/cc1plus -E -quiet -v -iprefix /gpfs7kro/gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/ -D_GNU_SOURCE - -mtune=generic -march=x86-64
ignoring nonexistent directory "/gpfs7kro/gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/gpfs7kro/gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../include/c++/8.3.0"
ignoring duplicate directory "/gpfs7kro/gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../include/c++/8.3.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
ignoring duplicate directory "/gpfs7kro/gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../include/c++/8.3.0/backward"
ignoring duplicate directory "/gpfs7kro/gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/gpfs7kro/gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/gpfs7kro/gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/include"
  as it is a non-system directory that duplicates a system directory
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /gpfslocalsys/intel/parallel_studio_xe_2019_update5_cluster_edition/compilers_and_libraries_2019.5.281/linux/mkl/include
 /gpfs7kro/gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../include/c++/8.3.0
 /gpfs7kro/gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../include/c++/8.3.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
 /gpfs7kro/gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../include/c++/8.3.0/backward
 /gpfs7kro/gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/include
 /gpfs7kro/gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/include-fixed
 /usr/local/include
 /gpfs7kro/gpfslocalsup/spack_soft/gcc/8.3.0/gcc-4.8.5-opnwtdjumg2hxo4ljvnx77ugb6afmvj3/bin/../lib/gcc/../../include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `gcc-8.3.0`?  Tensorflow 2.0 is compiled with `gcc-7.3.1`

Comment: This is because gcc 7.3.1 is not available on the cluster. Moreover, I have tried with the intel compiler the same thing and everytime I get such include errors. So, I believe the problem is somewhere in the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this PR from within spack for this : `https://github.com/spack/spack/pull/14681`